# Calculate String Width / Height on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

If I display a string in a custom field using drawtext(txt,ax,ay) method, how can I calculate the string width / height.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Width:

```
int stringWidth = getFont().getAdvance(yourString);`
```

Height:

```
int stringHeight = getFont().getHeight();`
```

Those are if you're making the calls from within one of your `Field`'s methods (meaning you have `extend`ed a `Field`). However, if you're simply trying to draw the string and are wondering what `ax` and `ay` represent, those are positions, not dimensions.

Comment: Also, there is a graphic in the Font javadoc that is valuable for understanding all the different dimensions that can be determined from a font: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Font.html

Comment: getFont().getHeight() just return the height of this font. But in some cases, if the font does not support some characters(e.g. Thai character), it would return the wrong height of text. So do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately my work has only been with pretty much the standard BB fonts, so I'm not sure how to get around that.